# How to flip a csv rows order while keeping headers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I would like to be able to flip a csv file rows but keep the headers.

## Current

```
timestamp       open      high       low     close     volume
2020-04-14 2805.1001 2851.8501 2805.1001 2846.0601 3113388741
2020-04-13 2782.4600 2782.4600 2721.1699 2761.6299 5274310000
 .....
2000-01-04 1455.2200 1455.2200 1397.4301 1399.4200 1009000000
2000-01-03 1469.2500 1478.0000 1438.3600 1455.2200 931800000
```

## Desired Result

```
timestamp       open      high       low     close     volume
2000-01-03 1469.2500 1478.0000 1438.3600 1455.2200 931800000
2000-01-04 1455.2200 1455.2200 1397.4301 1399.4200 1009000000
.....
2020-04-13 2782.4600 2782.4600 2721.1699 2761.6299 5274310000
2020-04-14 2805.1001 2851.8501 2805.1001 2846.0601 3113388741
```

I have been able to flip the data over with this, but I cannot retain the headers. Skip headers is added, else the headers are put on the bottom of the csv file.

## Current Code

```
 def reverse_csv():
    with open("spx.csv", "r") as infile, open("spx_cleaned.csv", "w") as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    next(reader, None)  # skip the headers
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in reversed(list(reader)):
        # process each row
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Thanks!

Comment: A sort would be way simpler: `df = pd.read_csv('in.csv'); df.sort_values('timestamp').to_csv('out.csv')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try the following?

```
pd.read_csv('input.csv').iloc[::-1].to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks! this is the output, is there a way to preserve 'timestamp' as the index rather than add the numbers? 

timestamp open high low close volume
5101 2000-01-03 1469.25 1478.0 1438.36 1455.22 931800000

Comment: You can just add the index=False parameter. Just updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use iloc:

```
df.iloc[::-1]
```

Comment: To make this answer more useful to readers of this question, consider adding a description to explain what you're doing and why your doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv('spx.csv')
df = df[::-1].reset_index(drop=True)
df.to_csv('spx_cleaned.csv')
```